# Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 - USB

Tags: raspbian, usb, pi-4, raspbian-buster

I am using the Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 & referring to the [Raspberry Pi DataSheet](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.org/cm4/cm4-datasheet.pdf).
Here I found that the Compute module has only one USB port.

I would like to use multiple USB ports & I don't want to add extra hardware.

How can I configure the compute module to access multiple USB ports?

Comment: Specifically the CM4 is the Core chips of a Raspberry PI 4 so whilst it supports USB it doesn't have any I/O on board.    For that you require a carrier board such as the CM4IO board which provides 2xUSB2.0 ports.  There are third party carrier boards which give can give you more USB ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its best that you use usb hubs.

unfortunately, that's the only choice i know and have...

it's something similar to this:-

https://in.images.search.yahoo.com/search/images;_ylt=Awr9Dts0ONxgAIAA5ES7HAx.;_ylu=Y29sbwNncTEEcG9zAzEEdnRpZANDMjAxMF8xBHNlYwNwaXZz?p=usb+hub&fr2=piv-web&type=E211US1289G0&fr=mcafee#id=24&iurl=https%3A%2F%2Frocstor.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2018%2F12%2FKNM0459.jpg&action=click